# Swagger with WebApi and OWIn

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, swagger, swashbuckle

I want to use Swagger to document my api based on .Net WebApi and Owin for OAuth. 
I use the Swashbuckle.Core Nuget Package and I configure swagger in my startup class:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        IContainer container = AutoFacConfig.Register(config, app);
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);


        ConfigureOAuth(app, container);

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        AutoMapperConfig.Register();

        config
           .EnableSwagger(c =>
          {
              c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "My API");
              c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlCommentsPath());
          })
           .EnableSwaggerUi();

        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
```

This is my GetXmlCommentsPath Method

```
protected static string GetXmlCommentsPath()
    {
        return System.String.Format(@"{0}\bin\My.WebApplication.XML", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
    }
```

If now I start my app I recive a StackOverFlowException and the Swagger Website told's me

```
Can't read from server. It may not have the appropriate access-control-origin settings.
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: How is the CORS settings in the API?

Comment: app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll)